# Как правильно писать "вуз"?

Tags: орфография, аббревиатуры

Аббревиатура "вуз" пишется большими или маленькими буквами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вуз - высшее учебное заведение — пишется строчными буквами: вуз.

Answer (score 2):

Аббр**Е**виатура "вуз" уже более полувека пишется строчными буквами.